# Question on applying negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, negative-binomial

> Let's assume we conduct an experiment which generates two outcomes: success $A$ or failure $B$. The experiment never generates more than $N$ failures. Both $A$ and $B$ have the same probability. After $N+1$ successes the experiment stops. What is the probability to see $m\geq0$ failures before the $(N+1)$-th success?

---

This looks like a negative binomial distribution, i.e. $P(m)={N+m\choose m}\frac{1}{2^{N+m+1}}$. However, in a negative binomial distribution $m$ is unbounded. Further, in the experiment we ca only see the outcomes $m=0,1,\dots,N$. Hence,
$$
P(m=0)+P(m=1)+\dots +P(m=N)=1.
$$
However, if we consider the binomial distribution it is certainly **not** the case that
$$
\sum\limits_{m=0}^N{N+m\choose m}\frac{1}{2^{N+m+1}}\color{red}{=}1.
$$

---

So I am wondering if this distribution is appropriate in this setting? How could we justify the application of the negative binomial distribution (if it is possible at all)?

Comment: The punchline is that once the $N$'th failure has occurred, all following outcomes will be $A$'s with no randomness associated with it.  It is false then that $\Pr(N)=\binom{2N}{N}\frac{1}{2^{2N+1}}$.  To use the negative binomial, the events needed to be independent, but this condition caused there to be dependence among the events.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer it is not.  That is the explanation of the traditional negative-binomial scenario.  This scenario differs thanks to the phrase "*The experiment never generates more than $N$ failures*"

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh right, then the situation is quite different. Thanks. The negative binomial is, for certain, not applicable. Since the success probability of every trial is $\frac 12$, perhaps there may be an argument that is easier than the one for general $p$.

Comment: I'd call it negative binomial for $m<N$ and then note that $P(N)=1-\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}P(m)$

Comment: @JMoravitz, why would it be negative binomial if $m<N$? I mean the same problems I have described above also remain in that case.

Comment: @JMoravitz Trying to understand your comment. Suppose that we did not stop the experiment after $N$ failures. Then, $NB(\frac 12,N+1)$ is the number of independent trials required until $N+1$ successes are recorded, where we do stop. Therefore, $NB(\frac 12,N+1) - (N+1)$ is the number of failures recorded before the $N+1$th success. The probability that this is at least $N$ equals the probability that the original experiment halts after $N$ failures (the $m=N$ case) and the probability that it halts at $m<N$ failures is the same as that of the original experiment halting after $m<N$ failures.

Comment: @Philipp: Are you *required* to apply the negative binomial distribution, or do you seek a suitable distribution for the experiment ?

Comment: In other words, let $X \sim NB(\frac 12,N+1) - (N+1)$ (the distribution of the number of failures until $N+1$ successes), and let $Y = X$ if $X<N$ and $Y=N$ if $X>N$. Then, $Y$ is precisely the distribution of failures before $N+1$ successes, *if* we were to stop at $N$ failures. The distribution of $X$ is clear, and as long as the given expression for $Y$ is correct, it should be easy to calculate its distribution, completing the task. I am just not fully sure yet that it's the $Y$ I describe which is correct, but if it is then I can write an answer.

Comment: @trueblueanil, , yes if possible then we must apply the negative binomial.

Answer (score 1):

With Wimbledon on, it strikes me that it would be easier to model it instead as a *truncated* binomial distribution (thus probabilities not adding up to $1$) in which you *lose* a $(2N+1)$ set match

$$P(m\geq 0)=\frac{1}{2^{2N+1}}\sum_{m=o}^N\binom{2N+1}{m}$$

---

**Added at OP's request**

To mould it into a negative binomial distribution, given $N+1$ successes, we find the number of trials $T$ (variant #2 of *Alternative Formulations* in Wikipedia)

$$P(X=T) = \binom{T-1}{N}p^{N+1}(1-p)^{T-N-1}$$

Of course, due to the conditions laid down,
$(N+1) \leq T \leq (2N+1)$,
so again, it is a truncated NB distribution.

Comment: @Philipp: As Christ said, "Man is not made for the Sabbath, the Sabbath is made for Man." Similarly,, we are not bound by the models, we can play with them to suit our purpose. This said, I suppose it could be better said that we used the NB *formula* rather than the NB *distribution.* For the tennis match, eg.  we use a series of NB formulas for matches  ending after $3,4, or 5$ sets. Btw, you would do well to look up the "Panjer class" which integrates the binomial, NB bi and the Poisson into one formula.  https://www.actuaries.org/ASTIN/Colloquia/Helsinki/Papers/S7_13_Fackler.pdf